# Will an OS X 10.7.4 installation and compiled binaries be compatible across Sandy/Ivy Bridge?

Tags: macos

Will a hard drive having OS X 10.7.4 which installed on a mid-2011 Sandy Bridge Mac just work if plugged into one of the mid-2012 Ivy Bridge Macs?

Will all binaries, including those installed by Macports/Homebrew be fully compatible?

Comment: I can say this: Ivy Bridge is backward compatible with Sandy Bridge.  Plain old binaries would be compatible for sure and I'd bet that you could boot from that old drive but you'll need to get verification from someone who's been there.  Are you trying to port your files and settings to a new Mac?  That's what [Migration Assistant](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4413) is for.

Comment: I'm hesitant to even try Migration Assistant since (1) it will take dozens of hours to work and (2) I have no reason to believe that it properly migrates all sorts of non-standard stuff that I have installed / configured.